# Configuring Java with NXT Lego robot

Tags: java, nxt

I have been trying to getting I got everything installed for leJOS on the NXT by the tutorial and I installed this Java 6 for it from
[Here](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572?locale=en_US&viewlocale=en_US).

I have tried to run a simple java program on the NXT but I keep getting this.
How do I fix this?

```
Error: This Java instance does not support a 32-bit JVM.
Please install the desired version.
Linking the file failed with exit status 1
```

Is there a way I can run 32bit java6 so that I can write programs for my NXT brick?

BTW the tutorial I have been following is from there

http://www.lejos.org/nxt/nxj/tutorial/Preliminaries/GettingStartedMac.htm